# Mañé's example of an attractor with no natural measure

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, examples, counterexamples

I'm reading Milnor's [notes](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ejack/DYNOTES/) on dynamical systems and in Lecture 3 he gives an example of an attractor with no natural measure, which he attributes to Mañé. I can find no other reference in which this example is discussed; no paper by Ricardo Mañé, no books or papers in which this example is mentioned. Milnor also states that an earlier paper by Zakharevich has a similar example, but again no reference is given, and I cannot find this paper anywhere. Has this or any other counterexample been published anywhere else? Any references would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q:** Has this or any other counterexample been published anywhere else?

**A:** In [A continuous Bowen-Mañé type phenomenon](https://www.aimsciences.org/journals/displayArticlesnew.jsp?paperID=3046) examples of vector fields without physical measure for certain parameters are discussed under the name "*Bowen-Mañé type phenomena*". No primary reference to either scientist is given.

The Bowen-Mañé example is also called "*Bowen's eye*" in the literature, see [arXiv: 2010.08945](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.08945) and [arXiv:1609.05356](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05356). The attribution to Bowen is due to Takens, who writes in a [1994 paper:](https://www.emis.de/journals/em/docs/boletim/vol251/v25-1-a6-1994.pdf)

> "I attribute this example to Bowen: although he never published it, I
> learned this example through a paper by Ruelle who referred to Bowen
> (we have no reference: even Ruelle could not localize that paper)."

[image]

<sub>[[source]](https://www.stefanoluzzatto.net/uploads/2/6/7/1/26719559/2017-09_tunisia.pdf)</sub>

Comment: Do you think "localize" = "locate" here?

Comment: yes, that is certainly what Takens meant.